# How to warmup Google Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I use Cloud Functions to call datastore. And every time its execution time are all >10 seconds.
Is there any method to reduce its execution time?
Please give me some suggestions, thanks.

code:

```
exports.sample_code = (req, res) => {
    let message = req.body.message;
    const gcloud = require('google-cloud');
    const datastore = gcloud.datastore({
        projectId: 'first-app'
    })

    const query = datastore
    .createQuery('monthly_r','p539')
    .filter('l_type','=',message);
    datastore.runQuery(query, function(err, entities) {
        console.log(entities);
        res.send("finish");
    });
```

};

result:

2020-04-07 01:17:59.624 Function execution took 12702 ms

2020-04-07 06:26:52.131 Function execution took 13223 ms

2020-04-09 18:36:29.301 Function execution took 11200 ms

Comment: it should not take > 10 seconds

Comment: it takes > 10 seconds every first time. And second time its execution time is --->[Function execution took 754 ms, finished with status code: 200].  How can I revise my code to make it every time < 2 seconds?

Comment: In the best [practices](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) you can find out how you can avoid "cold starts" in a Cloud Function.

Comment: Thank you  chainicko, I have solved the problem. I added too many dependencies in Cloud Functions.